# How to delete row from db table with 2 primary keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new using MVC C# on web applications...and I am having troubles deleting a row in the database...the result is an "HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request"

I'm not get this error when tables have just 1 primary keys.

Controller:

```
// GET: DocenteCursoes/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(string curso, string docente)
    {
        if (curso == null && docente == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        DocenteCurso docenteCurso = db.DocenteCurso.Find(curso, docente);
        if (docenteCurso == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(docenteCurso);
    }

    // POST: DocenteCursoes/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string curso, string docente)
    {
        DocenteCurso docenteCurso = db.DocenteCurso.Find(curso, docente);
        db.DocenteCurso.Remove(docenteCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Model:

```
[Table("DocenteCurso")]
public partial class DocenteCurso
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Curso { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Docente { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

Comment: A table doesn't have two primary keys. A primary key is defined as a *single* key for the table. A key may be a composite key formed from multiple columns, however.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are getting `BadRequest` due to this condition:

```
if (curso == null && docente == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Which has nothing to do with whatever or not your entity has a composite primary key.
Make sure you are calling a correct controller action.

Note that `Html.BeginForm()` with no parameters, sends an HTTP POST to the current URL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's start with a well-constructed URL like this :

```
http://yourserver/DocenteCursoes/Delete?curso=firstparam&docente=secondparam
```

Try that in an Internet browser first, and tell me if you could get rid of the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, new { curso = Model.Curso, docente = Model.Docente })) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about how this answers the question.

Comment: When you use Composite key in ASP.NET MVC Model, you need to define **routeValues** object in **Html.BeginForm()**.

Comment: **Html.BeginForm(string actionName, string controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues);**